# Using a Kindle Paperwhite screen with raspberry

Tags: screen

I recently broke the screen of my [Kindle Paperwhite](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07CXG6C9W), basically almost 1/3 of the bottom screen is still with the cover image and doesnt get updated.

So instead of throwing it away, I was wondering if is possible to connect the screen to a raspberrypi zero to make something creative, i dont know maybe a smart frame or something
The working area of the screen is still pretty big

Anyone know if is possible, and which hardware is necessary?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I'm glad you asked the question. Kinda off-topic of your question, but I'm interested because when I bought my Paperwhite, Amazon charged an extra $20 to disable their on-screen advertisements. I've despised Amazon ever since, so I'm hoping someone has a good answer for this. :)    [This search looks promising](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=hacking+the+kindle+paperwhite&t=ffnt&ia=web)

Comment: [This one looks interesting.](https://gizmodo.com/hack-your-kindle-to-use-it-as-a-raspberry-pi-screen-5942166) It's the reverse of what you're trying to do, but there may be good clues.

Comment: @Seamus that is EXACLTY what im tryin to achive! post it as an answer so i can upvote. Honestly in those days i dont have the time to try it, but i'll as soon as I have the time

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](https://gizmodo.com/hack-your-kindle-to-use-it-as-a-raspberry-pi-screen-5942166), it can be done.  I'm not sure how the broken Kindle screen will play in this, but as it's strictly *command-line* (using `screen` - [maybe `tmux` or `dtach`](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffnt&q=alternative+to+screen&ia=software) as well?), perhaps you can set the terminal size to avoid the broken area?

The author calls this project "***The KindleBerry Pi***", and he provides some [details on getting it to work](http://ponnuki.net/2012/09/kindleberry-pi/).

The article is getting a bit old (date stamp is 2012), and at least one of the links is broken. However - good news! [Work has continued on **KindleBerry Pi**](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffnt&q=KindleBerry+Pi&ia=web). Since yours is a Kindle Paperwhite you may find this [article on KindleBerry Pi 2 interesting](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/kindleberry-pi-the-second/). Even more currently, this article from 2019 claims a [KindleBerry Pi Zero](https://www.meccanismocomplesso.org/en/kindleberry-the-economic-ultraportable-laptop-with-kindle-and-raspberry-pi/) may be used - but it's paired with a Kindle Touch.

Good luck & do let us know how you get on.